# Active the button in Dialog box Android

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener, dialog

I got error when i add the button function in onListItemClick, here's my code.

```
 public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View view, int position, long id){
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this.getActivity());
    dialog.setTitle("Dicoba dialog");
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.my_dialog);
    dialog.show();

    Button btnYes = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.yes);
    Button btnNo = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.no);

    btnYes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Yes!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    btnNo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
}
```

I want to active the button in dialog box.
What should i do?

Thank You!

Comment: post your error please

Comment: @mango23 ... Please check below solution... It will helpful of you

Comment: Its perfect .I guess . Problem here `(Button) getActivity()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dialog` instead of `getActivity()` ;

```
Button btnYes = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.yes);
Button btnNo = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.no);
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the code with these lines of code

```
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View view, int position, long id){
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this.getActivity());
    dialog.setTitle("Dicoba dialog");
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.my_dialog);
    dialog.show();

    ///// IN PLACE OF FINDING IDS OF THE BUTTON FROM GETVIEW...YOU SHOULD UES THE DIALOG REFERENCE AS BELOW:-


    Button btnYes = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.yes);
    Button btnNo = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.no);

    btnYes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Yes!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    btnNo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
}
```